# Park, Lake, Santa Fe

Tags: code-golf, string, subsequence

Given a long multi-sentence string, the goal is the count the occurrences of the following words: `park`, `lake`, `Santa Fe`.

The words can appear as substrings of other words, i.e, `parked` counts as an instance of `park`.

`Santa Fe` counts as one word (so the space matters). Both `Santa` and `Fe` appearing alone or out of order does **not** count as an instance of `Santa Fe`.

The output should be counts of the number of times the words `park`, `lake`, and `Santa Fe` appear in the input string, in any consistent and readable format and order.

For example, for an input of

```
I'm just parked out by the lake; the lake 80 miles from Santa Fe. That's where i'm parked, out by the lake.
```

the output would resemble

```
2 3 1
```

as there are \$2\$ occurrences of `park`, \$3\$ of `lake` and \$1\$ of `Santa Fe`.

Good luck! If you want a fun song to test this on you can use the lyrics to [Parked by the lake - Dean Summerwind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_zS_uiPWxs) (below) and use it as the input; The output ought to be `20 24 14`.

Winning submission is the least number of bytes.

---

[Lyrics to Parked by the Lake](https://tio.run/##5ZTNboMwEITvfoq9cclLNGorceqhkaoeHbGAi38q22nE01OvMWBCEqXnnvgR83lmvMZJ7lp0w1AWCpwXUsI3tx1WYE4ejj34FkHyDtmLaFrfgxISHdTWKHjn2nN4RfakK4h64b3QBbRoEb5Ozt9isbKG3pyK8NnZ6Aotqc5RViYNIyDpEiKXl75w81O44fSMt/3NBv8e7epSCZMMBy73GyYt6VvhRmG4Ll@ngI8UerkhkRGXSeR7FPZsqGWwqFAd0Ub7YGQ1Kg/BqtERN0sOY8BVsmVnm8VDynDZ7OLvsakRm3rXjvOZ@LfbSBhnFFa8j6eiMVpzUOYH2T7ALElBm3PuijTUZEfvY68xwBiPTezdVEXewS7nfHARj3RtLPHYFfCdHfncTF/mYtvTGCzM2mrG3ibo1NXmxX5ZkvZwaS7/KV2ObpnlBk@ngmK1VCPUKP2KKvRMHYZf)

Comment: Also, for future reference, we suggest using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first to get feedback :)

Comment: I will definitely use that next time, my apologies!

Comment: Is input case sensitive? If input is  `"Park park PARK."`, should I output 3 for park or 1?

Comment: Suggested example: `Santa fed his reindeer and changed the spark plugs on his sleigh, then slaked his thirst with a nice glass of milk`...

Comment: Suggest testcase `ppaparparkllalaklakeSSaSanSantSantaSanta Santa FSanta Fe` with answer \$1,1,1\$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
„†¹Š°#„š´º´™ª¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZSxbsIwFEX3fMUTHbLwE0VtpUwdilR1NMoLcUnsyjFF2Rj6HRVl7NSBpR0j8SP8SOrnJMQhgOjcCRzlHt97/RyZsQnHstwt33fLVfG9XRVfV2ax/Sg2xU@x2b2ti89iXZaDwSDwU8g0TxJ4YWqGIci5hkkOOkZI2Ay9Wz6NdQ4pTzCDSMkUHpjQDO7QuxYhWD3XmgsfYlQIz/NMn2J5QQS5nPvmtYUUISpSLawsqDUeAUlXI1x5oP1svzJ/GK3xtL@9wb9HO7pVjakNGy7TPSZtqWOeVULz275dB7yk0MMDsQy7TU0@R/FuJLUMClNMJ6isfZBJWCnHxqoUFreXjKuAnWTtyU5bD3WGw2Zbf5dNDe/V23XszsS/PUbCZDLFkOX2VkylEAxS@YreyMAUSUHIheuKNNTkjJ7bXm2AKp7XsIdNFW4HQ5fzyLi90pFUxPOOgM@cyFNv@hwX/Z6qYGbWOjN230CbrnoPRu2WdIZtc@5H6XB0Ayc3aLoVFCumGiHCRHeoXOyp5lv5Cw)

```haskell
„†¹Š°            -- compressed string  => "park lake"
     #           -- split on spaces    => ["park", "lake"]
      „š´º´      -- compressed string  => "santa fe"
           ™     -- title cased        => "Santa Fe"
            ª    -- append to the list => ["park", "lake", "Santa Fe"]
             ¢   -- for each word, count the number of occurences in the input
```

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>36</sup> 30 bytes

```
1#.('Santa Fe';park`lake)E.&><
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZRfS8MwFMXf8ykuCsZBLfNNNhWcblAQBB2Ib2Y2XbO1ibSZo59@5qb/snUb89mHQSk5v3vOye0WmzOfRnA3AAoe9GFgflc@PL4@TzbX5/4lfWNSM5hwOvxm2fIzYUveG/sX97ebHuFfsYIIaEBpCotVrgHP8BDUSsOsAB1zQMGweYKbPqQi4TlEmUqhhvswjZmmNId1zDMOAoEly9uF@bSea9z2SWBO5lokyYHZZCzmsS72TSUPMgSrF1oLScHOPpKDkCCCQq2oObZWMuQZqkrLQaWxhlBXIVx5oE3CpgqNkXPgh/01Bv8ebe@oClMZNlymO0wcqWORl0KRO6ergKcUunshlmHHVORjFPKksGXIeMrTGc@sfVBJWCqnxqqSFtdIpmXArWTtzc5bD1WG3WZbf6dtjejUu@3Y3Yl/e42IyVXKQ1bYr2KupGSQqh9ORgaWoRSkWruuUINNLvG97dUGKOORmu3VVbgdeC7nnQn7SUcqQx7ZAz5yIx@d7XNcdHsqg5ld29qxlxpad9V5MWpH4h22zbl/SrurGzi5QeNXgbFirBEinugtqpAttbf5BQ)

*-5 thanks to Bubbler!*

Returns count in order "Santa Fe", "park", "lake".

- `E.` Does all the matching work, returning three rows of ones and zeros, where ones represent the start of each match.
- `1#.` Sums row-wise.

Comment: 31 bytes ``1#.<E.~&>park`lake,<@'Santa Fe'`` by avoiding rank fiddling, and then 30 bytes ``1#.('Santa Fe';park`lake)E.&><`` by reordering the output (I think it's allowed by the line "in any consistent and readable format and order")

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda k:map(k.count,["park","lake","Santa Fe"])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZQ/T8MwEMV3f4pTlrRSxMCIxEAFSJkYqIQQMLjEaUxiO3Icqnz64HP@OQ2tysyUxPL7@d27c8rGZEpet@nte1tQsUso5DeClqv86lPV0kRvQUl1HkRBQXNmH89UGgqPLPhYt6Xm0qzSVRAEcSigMrwoALezBFRtYNeAyRigkjzwfWYaELxgFaRaCRhI5E4m4PTcGC5DyJhm8FVX5hSLxCk0qg7ttoOSCdOoOjhZ3GsIAlHXI3x5bMJq/LIvFL/ZaX@jwb@X9utRPaY3bLnULJh4pMl41Qntc9rdF3hJoMcNcQx3TE8@RyH3ClMGzQQTO6adfVBF0im31qqSDjdKtl2Bs8qmzu4nD30Nx8lO/i6bGr6Id@7Yn4l/20bEVEqwhDbuVuyVlBSE@mZkY2EapSDVwXeFGkwyx3WXqyugK48M7GiIws8g8jkvlLsrnSqNPPIL@ExHXhfT57lY5tQVZmdtNmNPA3TIarGwmY7EHk7J@T@l49GNvbrB4K3AsjKMEVJWmBmVy5Fq/5XrdfsD)

-7 bytes thanks to tsh

Comment: Python 2: `lambda s:map(s.count,["park","lake","Santa Fe"])` or Python 3: `lambda s:[*map(s.count,["park","lake","Santa Fe"])]`

Comment: @tsh oh yeah, been a while since I've done this. thanks

Comment: FYI, `[*...]` is not necessary in Python 3 since [outputting a generator in place of a list is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/78410).

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
ẆċⱮ“£Ḟœ“ċẈ“¡ç1Ḋı»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrYj3Y82rnvUMOfQ4oc75h2dDGQd6X64qwMksvDwcsOHO7qObDy0@////0qe6rkKWaXFJQoFiUXZqSkK@aUlCkmVCiUZqQo5idmp1nCWgoWBQm5mTmqxQlpRfq5CcGJeSaKCW6qeQkhGYol6sUJ5RmpRqkIm0DiISTroRukpAQA)

-2 bytes thanks to [Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy)

### How it works

```
ẆċⱮ“£Ḟœ“ċẈ“¡ç1Ḋı» - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
Ẇ                 - Yield all contiguous sublists of S
   “£Ḟœ“ċẈ“¡ç1Ḋı» - Compressed string list; ["park", "lake", "Santa Fe"]
  Ɱ               - Over each string:
 ċ                -   Count the occurrences in the sublists
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 16 bytes

```
`⟇æ
»¥
ʁ∨ Fe`↵vO
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%60%E2%9F%87%C3%A6%0A%C2%BB%C2%A5%0A%CA%81%E2%88%A8%20Fe%60%E2%86%B5vO&inputs=I%27m%20just%20parked%20out%20by%20the%20lake%3B%20the%20lake%2080%20miles%20from%20Santa%20Fe.%20That%27s%20where%20i%27m%20parked%2C%20out%20by%20the%20lake.&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
`...`↵vo
`...`      # the string "park\nlake\Santa Fe"
     ↵     # split on newlines to form a list
      vo   # for each in that list, get the count in the input
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work on all inputs, i used the entire lyrics of the song https://i.imgur.com/TqbX07t.png

Comment: @Taako that's because you need to wrap it in `"` and replace the newlines with `\n`

Comment: I don't think you need the `S` flag, as the output format has been loosened

Comment: [16 with `r`](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%60%E2%9F%87%C3%A6%0A%C2%BB%C2%A5%0A%CA%81%E2%88%A8%20Fe%60%E2%86%B5vO&inputs=I'm%20just%20parked%20out%20by%20the%20lake%3B%20the%20lake%2080%20miles%20from%20Santa%20Fe.%20That's%20where%20i'm%20parked%2C%20out%20by%20the%20lake.&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 58 bytes

```
[ { "park" "lake" "Santa Fe" } [ count-subseq ] with map ]
```

`count-subseq`:

- Doesn't exist in build 1525 (the one TIO uses).
- Has stack effect `( subseq seq -- n )` in every build that permits the omission of whitespace after strings.
- Has stack effect `( seq subseq -- n )` in the current build, which means we don't need an extra `swap`.

Therefore, the code retains the whitespace after strings but it's still shorter than the alternatives. Also, have a picture.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>124</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>106</s></sup> 103 bytes

```c
*f(int*s){int c[3]={},i;for(;*s;++s)for(i=3;i--;)c[i]+=!wcsncmp(s,L"parklakeSanta Fe"+i*4,4<<i/2);s=c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZZdb9owFIbv@yvOIrESCG35mLQtZdO6dRJSpV200jQ1XLiJAx6Jg2J3wBB/fezYzidpUbXrIQHBx@9z3nPsxPi9me/v952wzbjsCHuLX@DfD6fj7c5hbpikbbcj3G5X2OqajYcu6/Vc279n0@741coX3I@XbeHcWEuSLiKyoLeESwJfqdVlnZEzurxk5wPbFWPf3e0VPSaMt23YngC@VFaQVEhxP4UxbG@syWkMPx@FBMWjASSPEh42IOcUFN0truDtBcQsogLCNIkhT3sGd3MiTwWs5jSlwBBnSM4h6sxytIfDl/EgJIuiZ0x4/JrN5nLzVH6Pf@IBaAKTkvFT0D6OlORxj09C2CSPpzhxlfCApkpnCphkKpyDTCXNKDXCRFVcdEaaDtAjJkub/1Lik@kyUGYbyUQ2qSqrnDNhlExUpud1vqi3h6ujKTpTxj7O8fiXRHUcUhrT@IGmughIoiAT36HjhGtkqartrKzCcqVnpZG8lEaXS5sv3Ums0eq67@ou@b@smiSSmAZkY@6YWcI5gTj5heErJKZKDjxZ1cwpmWrrQgV0k3Uhpk6P5xmcvCnVbjg10nfC9F2Pj0tFzD3V4ccW6EdjV1asPNEzUyBuwfrW@5Zzi8Y1R67KvGpVq32sPsAa23pSaQFIddOo8uaqpxDSSNbJjBfkZ5@4yyVBuD5CIoIqfZDcEtQpqZYbRkYqgJq3c/PDBOh6SX1Jg745TwYODB3o75wiMMgCFw4MRhgaYawIDk2wj@NG1ckjJlDQK7zyclj66IA/p/6CpkZneevrgbd@9xnfbywHqr@HViZTO0Ydw6gP6BplF252eYlL8ZsmYTvPZJ9nA4U/24VuV8/Oj9bCiUCUOWJ1fOoW4SWeMzJsW57VioRnQe8DoDlhu3WAj4Cw3RimOFy05xCt6lgSoXL3y9GyxKw8LG2onVddV621RCtAT@yj6tp7Cz/VX4@KFT1ZJXo91iEYoyv8LmfsGvVCS3hcobI1UvqcuTvZ7f/4YURmYt9b/QU)

Saved <s>a</s> 2 bytes and fixed a bug thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

Inputs a string.
Return a pointer to an array of occurrence counts for `park`, `lake`, and `Sante Fe`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 33 bytes

```
g;"park
lake
Santa Fe"ṇᵗz{{sᵈ}ᶜ}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bG8v/p1koFiUXZXDmJ2alcwYl5JYkKbqlKD3e2P9w6vaq6uvjh1o7ah9vm1D7cOuH/fyVP9VyFrNLiEgWQntQUhfzSEoWkSoWSjFQFkAHWcJaChYFCbmZOarFCWlF@rgLMYD2FkIzEEvVihfKM1KJUhUygcRCTdNCN0lMCAA)

I'm not sure if this feels very golfable, or not even remotely golfable... `⟨s≡⟩ᶜ` happens to tie `{sᵈ}ᶜ`, so maybe there's some shenanigan to pull there, but that seems doubtful.

```
g;                    Wrap the input in a list, and pair it with
  "..."               "park\nlake\nSanta Fe"
       ṇᵗ             split on newlines.
         z            Cycling zip.
          {     }ᵐ    For each pair [input, park/lake/Santa Fe]:
           {  }ᶜ      in how many ways
            sᵈ        is park/lake/Santa Fe a substring of the input?
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup>59</sup> 51 bytes

```bash
grep -Eo 'park|lake|Santa Fe'|sort|uniq -c|awk NF=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZS9boMwFIV3P8XdWJKhD9ChUROJpR0aqerolAu4ATu1TRES70655s@EJErnTvyI8/mc42sO3KRNk2g8wXqrIDhxfawzfsT6jUvLYYdBbZS2dSHFN6w/a14e4WX3@NA0YZCDsSLLgEQYgSosHCqwKQIR2FYkqa0gFxkaiLXKYWCyJxmB0wtrhQwgRY3wVRh7jcXCGCpVBO1npZIRalKVThb2GkZA0vUIXx7awIxP7Q2nZ7zubzT492gXl@oxveGWy@2CSUvaVJhO2F6nr/uA9xR6viGO4Zbpybco7FlRy6Axx/yA2tkHlUWdct9aVdLhRsm@CzhLNu1sMnnoM5w3O/m7b2rEot65Y38m/u02EsaoHCNeuVORKCk55OoH2aaFaZKCVKXvijTU5JHeu15dgC4eG9iroQq/g5XPeefCHelYaeKxC@AbO/KxmD7PxbKnLlg7a7MZex2gQ1eLF5tpSdrDqTn/p3Q@uqGXGyydCoqVUo0QY2ZnVCFH6i8)

*-8 bytes thanks to [user41805](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41805/user41805)'s nice awk trick!*

Returns in order "lake", "park", "Santa Fe".

Comment: The awk statement can be simplified to `NF=1`

Comment: @user41805 TIL. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

```javascript
s=>["park","lake","Santa Fe"].map(w=>s.split(w).length-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZTNbpwwFIX3PMXVbABpgtoHmEiN2kissphIVVV14QwXcMbYE/tOEE8/9TUwMEMSpeuu@BHn8znH1zyLV@F2Vh7oRpsCT@Xm5Da3v1cHYfer9UqJPfrLVmgScI@rP1kjDkm7uXWZOyhJSZtmCnVF9c3X9KQ6K3cONmDx5SgtJnHp4jSzKIp7qXDb6V3yJc3IbMlKXSVptDPaGYWZMlVSJr0@TU953IAjqRSwDyzAHAmeOqAagS1FP2RVUweNpzoorWlgtBh90wUEvSSSOoYaLcLz0dF7rCgvoTPH2H/WGl2gZVUbZPmgiRjIugExl@cUu/OTvxH8jO/7Oxv892hvLjVgBsOeK2jB5CWplq4X@uv09RDwM4Veb0hghGUG8keU6Lvhlv1oNNg8oQ32waiiVz56q0YH3Fny2Ae8SDbtbDV5GDJcNzv5@9zUyEW9l47nM/HfbiNjnGmwEF04FZXRWkBjXjG68zDLUtCmnbtiDTe55/eh1xCgjxeN7PVYxbyD9ZzzU8hwpEtjmRe9Af5gR34tpm/mYtlTH8zP2sWMPYzQsavFi7tpSd7Dqbn5T@l6dPNZbiA@FRyr5hqhREUXVKnP1L8)

```javascript
s=>[(g=w=>s.split(w).length-1)`park`,g`lake`,g`Santa Fe`]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZTPbqMwEMbvfoq5AVKKug9ApVbdSpz2kEqrqlopbhjAjbFT2yni6bMeA4GEtuqe98Qf8f3mm2/GvPJ3brdG7N2V0gUey@xos5vnuMra7Mamdi@Fi9sklagqV1/9SDZ7bnabVbWRfId0XXPlODzg5s9RdkZsLWRg8O0gDMZRaaMkNciLByFx3altfJ2kTq@dEaqKE7bVymqJqdRVXMa9PkmOedSAdUJKoGpYgD44eOnA1QhUl/0UVe06aDzVQml0A6MNdqsKCHrhnFAR1GgQXg/WfcZieQmdPkT@s1arAg2p2iDLBw0jIOkGxFyeu8ienvwNp2f83N/J4L@39mGpATMY9lzuFkwq6Wphe6G/Tl8PDX4n0MuBBEYoM5C/orB7TSn71WiweUET7IOWRa989Fa1CriT5LFv8KyzabLV5GHo4TLZyd/3tkYs4j13PN@J/3aMhLG6wYJ34VRUWikOjX5HdudhhqSgdDt3RRpKckfvQ66hgb49NrJXYxTzDFZzzm8uwpEutSEe@wD8xUSeFts3c7HMqW/M79rZjv0aoWNWixd3U0ma4ZTc/Kd0ubr5rG9wdCqorZpihBKlO6MKdaL@BQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 21 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`pk
lake
SÂ Fe`·£èX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YHCHawpsYWtlClPCHCBGZWC3o%2bhY&input=IkknbSBqdXN0IHBhcmtlZCBvdXQgYnkgdGhlIGxha2U7IHRoZSBsYWtlIDgwIG1pbGVzIGZyb20gU2FudGEgRmUuIFRoYXQncyB3aGVyZSBpJ20gcGFya2VkLCBvdXQgYnkgdGhlIGxha2UuIg)

Comment: I'd love to know how you got around not writing the 'ar' in 'park' and the 'anta' in 'Santa'!

Comment: String compression, @Pureferret. There are 2 unprintables in it, one after the `p` and the other after the `Â`; charcodes `135` & `28`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```ruby
p %w[park lake Santa\ Fe].map{|r|$_.scan(r).size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZRNT4QwEIbv/oo5aNBkJR5NPGnUhJMHNzFGjOlKWerClLRFgq5/XewHn8u62Xj2RqDzzPu@M0UUi6quczgqn3IiVpCSFYV7goqEcEuf/Yzkn2uxPnzx5SvBY3HiS/ZBv@o68DJ4K6QCU0Yj4IWCRQUqoZZx0T3B@RlkLKUSYsEzx9ZoH@YJUZ6EMqGCAtM4R5ptovwD00sqlqa/NAvxhi0TVW3rE@IlRmAJTCmGHth@O6SHGGIQQ8ULTx8sOUZUmDonNGiq9BnNNKUNZUQIjLMuAeWc0h0ie5l/sbi1XQNqZGsyUVOq6aoSJl0lk4Pjrc@9st2cjqXYTg17NyfEa24SB0Ezmi2osCaAp1FTPNeKOVpkXzXaoMZhP@llL6S1Mkm5l7nvJrFJ1GPdwy35H6slSZ7RiFTuxiw5IoGMv@vPV5ooTDkgL0fiTJmJdWU@2JCtEeczxLbDrA1lmMZsRHogzN76mAtDbDWN4bsG9DjZyoGULZk5g3oFx6t313K74KZvrvq@ZqrDHIc/sMlaB4MIQJlLY@wlJlOIaarGZIYd@ZvninGU9Sn@AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [WolframLanguage (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), 50 bytes

```
(f|->f~StringCount~#&/@{"park","lake","Santa Fe"})
```

The above won't work in tio.run because |-> is too new (introduced in MMA v. 12.2, while tio.run uses MMA 12.0).

Thus here's a 51-byte version that does:

```
(f=#;f~StringCount~#&/@{"park","lake","Santa Fe"})&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZRPa8JAEMXv@RRDBG1BbI8FEaz9A55aUCileFibTbI1u1s2Y0VK/ep2Z5OYxFhrzz0lhH2/mfdmNpJhzCVD8cq20WB7Fg5a/XAzQSNUdKOXCjet9sXw039nZuF3/YQtuH1MmEIG99z/Om9vH@1ZHEYv/rgj4W2ZItBhHoBeIszXYAsA6frFC1xdghQJTyE0WkIB601jhp0UVjE3HISFZZzuHqfnz7xazRRFkvxQ1LsTUYzrQ/W8axWA0wtEoTrg6h4x4I1DWOtlx55aaRVwQ6Ks23Eu8YhHspxQU5O5XQaYmeW/t/d3Ywcr5Zi8X8tl2GBSSYxFmglFWjmd@zslzv1xOIYrk5OPUW41ZQyGSy7n3LjuQSdBJpzaTrVytJ2itja5sXKsUdlCbmEv17K70zZGNMKtN1xdiH86Q6KkWvKArd2FiLRSDKT@4N7IsgwpQelVtSnSUI4L@u5Sdf1n7rwC3S2SqEbQrXKemHCXOdSGeAe4R@bx3Ni8ShPNlDJfds9q@/VQQIukGh9GZUmaYDnzys9of2vHFdeAdCHIVUwhQsgTrEGF2kH92fYb)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 55 bytes

```clj
#(for[r[#"park"#"lake"#"Santa Fe"]](count(re-seq r %)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZRPT8JAEMXv@ykmJYaSIPFo4kmiJj150MQYwmGhU7rS7uJ2K/LpcWf7b6FA9OyJ0nR@896b2V1m6qPUuA9jTCDZD8JE6ZmeDYIN1@tgEGR8jfbnhUvD4QmD@TxcqlKaUON1gZ@g4Wo0Gu1HLIwV/Z/B94wF0TCHj7IwQBSMQZUGFjswKQIB79onuL2BXGRYQKJVDk2bCbym3AwL2KaoEYTFVaTxMWoSVN0KI7LsTDv2KFap2Z1qxO5lDK5eGCPkEFy/C9IZixLYqXJoP9sqGaOmqkpmVNcwAlJdjfDLI3LVujeVSzyvrxX4d2snW9WYWrDlctNjUkuTiqIqFIX3dW3wN4EeD8QxXJuafInCHhSlDBpzzBeonXxQWVxVvlqpSjpcW3KwMbWzbrKrTkPt4TjZTt/vtkb04j1U7O/Evx0jYQqVY8x37lSslJQccvWFbGphmkpBqq2vimooyTW9d7k6A5U91rDHTRR@BmOf88aFO9L2RiMeOwG@MJH33vZ5Kvo5Vcbsrh3s2HMDbbLqvZh2LWmGXXL@pXS8upHnGwydCrKVUoyQYGYOqEK21IDN5yzc2CvLZBLCBL7p7v4B)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), 73 bytes

```
foreach([park,lake,'Santa Fe']as$r)echo~-count(explode($r,$argv[1])).' ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcyxCsIwFIXhVzlDIAlEwVnBTXB2LB0u6W0ibXNDjKKLrx7toMsZfg5fjrkdjvm7oxQmH02XqUxupomdvlCqhBPrnm6qWPZR3hsv91QNP/MsAxtVnKISHt2ut3arofettbNeEOSaAqpg9bB6@HH/urzgqYDSAKYKwrj@Pg)

Comment: posted at the same time as my answer.. which could be improved by a `foreach` like in yours ;)

Comment: Great PHP minds think alike. Nice use of substr_count in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) -F, <s>71</s> <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```php
foreach([park,lake,"Santa Fe"]as$w)echo~_.substr_count($argn,$w);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3NCoJAFAXgV7mIoMEkLQODdkLr2kXI1a6N6fwwcwdp06M3KVGLNocDB75jpY27vZ2zM46wlfnZohvEiAOJ5IiaESpKLujTaUWtNM@68KHx7OrWBM15iu6mxTyWMR4yBffgGRaCrmACQ/MAlgSLV/4abDeg@pE8dM4o@N4UcJLImYdJkiPoZ@4jiX@qeBnLvdE@rqs3)

Just using dedicated function and usual tricks..

EDIT: 5 bytes saved using a `foreach` like in [Guillermo Phillips's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231829/90841)

EDIT 2: another byte the dust thanks to Guillermo Phillips again!

Comment: Save a byte by echoing the space first.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 39 bytes

```
{+/`park`lake`"Santa Fe"=/:`$(4'x),8'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJy9zU0LgjAAh/H7PsUfEWYk2ttBNroGnesmwhZtaGrGnDQR++wlUYc+QLfn9Hs0G+axuElTikqWSngHebUSO+VtYyb8YEPdLEyoGwmxbPDT/mGYBuC4aEoeCC2LijveczPLRmJTb09rXLrWYjLVGU1ncephc4VpwL+FZIG6qFQLbZoan2+EYy4tbXHPlVEoXtxbCn+pyOMrrLHMCIn/un0CpIpjbQ==)

- `(4'x),8'x` build a list containing all 4-length sliding windows, and all 8-length sliding windows, of the input
- `` `$ `` convert the slices from strings to symbols
- `` `park`lake`"Santa Fe"=/: `` build a matrix with each of its three columns indicating whether or not each slice of the input is equal to one of the search terms
- `+/` sum column-wise, returning the number of times `park`, `lake`, and `Santa Fe` appear in the input (respectively)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 bytes

```perl
for$w("park","lake","Santa Fe"){say s/$w//g}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcyxCsIwGATgVzlCoQptE4eC4F5wcNIXiPjXxqZJSVJLEV/d2CI6ON0Nd19PTpcx1tYl44r10rUsY1q2NMdRmiBREVs/vJzgeTJyfn3GuE873AYfsOzpAjsEnCeEhrBcd7@GrUCnNHnUznb4ggVOjQypx9iQI6iZ@0jZP1W8bB@UNT7mRsT8cC@LjXgD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), 45 bytes

```
for x (park lake Santa\ Fe)grep -o $x F|wc -l
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dc2xDoIwFIXhnac4gwk6dHcycbCJs6tLkQutFEra2wjGN3EhGh-Kt1HB1elM_3fuz2vQw2MjX5ELsR5F4Tw6LFvlK1hVEQ6qYXWEpFXpqYVwWHSQt8sJws7R8JvR7tMagY21-PaUw0VG1oM1TViyM6XmHrWxFFB4V8_8R0-2TY6pN8ymSaHJE84x8B9rPn0D)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 63 bytes

```
Cells A3:C3 = park, lake, Santa Fe (16 bytes)
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,A3:C3,"")))/{4,4,8}  (47 bytes)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnFdK4ZBRIJbqvADm?e=bpuFwo)

The easiest way to count occurrences of a substring is to substitute the substring with "" and then divide the difference in length by the length of the substring.

### Self contained formula, 68 bytes

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{"park","lake","Santa Fe"},"")))/{4,4,8}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 24 bytes

```
*M`park
*M`lake
Santa Fe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VRBboMwELz7FXtDqvKJRm0lDlUPjVT1VkcswQ22I7NpxOup1xgwIYnSc0/Glmd2ZnaNQ1JGdt3D69dBur3way33KN6lIQkv2HV5pqEhVdfAF7AAeyTYtkAVQrj6rHYVtaBVjQ2UzmoYwOLRFBDwinyZDCp0CN/Hhq5xibyE1h4zf@1kTYGOUacAyyNGMCHjIkUKzylrxp3/kLzH6/pGgX@3drFUpImCPa@kBSeXpEo1PdCv0@1o8J5AzxsSOEKZyHyLRTxZThkcatRbdEE@2LrokRsv1ZpAN0I2vcGZs6mzu0lD9HCe7KTvvqlRi3jnitOZ@LdtZJrGaixkG17FzhojQdsfFGtP5hgKxp5SVYzhJPd8HnINBnp747NfDVGkGaxSng@pwpMurWM@cYH4Rkc@F9OXqFjm1BvzszabsbeBdMhqcbCeSnIPp@TSn9L56OaJbyB@FWyr4hihxJpmrMqMrL8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
*M`park
```

Explicitly print the count of matches of the word `park` without changing the input buffer.

```
*M`lake
```

Explicitly print the count of matches of the word `lake` without changing the input buffer.

```
Santa Fe
```

Count the matches and implicitly print the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＩＥ⪪”&/‽∕“⎇⊙g…3ＣπΦＰ6”¶№θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZRRb4IwFIXf@ytueAET9gv2NN2W8LBsiSbLMvdQpUhnaV0pGn496y0gIGrc83xBCOfrOae3rFOq14qKqnrTXJpgRnMTvNBdMN8JbgJvR/V2KQXdsqWcU2koPDMvBG8pvUkIM1VYzU8IfGJ/91X16XkeifwMcsOFAFSzGFRhYFWCSRkgiTzxTWpKyLhgOSRaZdCiyYOMwem5MVz6kDLN4LvIzSUWiRIoVeHb1w5Kxkyj6uBkUaNxhlDXIPryyPj58c7@oXjPLvs7Gvx7tLNLNZjGsOVSM2LikibleS201@7tJuAthZ5uiGO4ZRryNQp5VNgyaJaxbMW0sw9KxLVyYa0q6XBHyaIOOEjW7eym89BkOG2283fb1PBRvUPH/Zn4t9uImFxlLKalOxUbJSWFTO0ZmVqYRilIdei7Qg02ucXnrlcXoI5HWnbYVtHvIOxz3il3RzpRGnnkDPjKjnyMpq/nYtxTHczO2mDGXlto29XowbRbEvewa67/UTod3aiXGwyeCoyVYo2QMGEGVC47qv1aflV3e/EL) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   ”...”        Compressed string `park\nlake\Santa Fe`
  ⪪     ¶       Split on newlines
 Ｅ              Map over each substring
         №      Count of
           ι    Current substring
          θ     In original input
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```